# Where can I visualize the workouts (com.google.activity.exercise) inserted using the REST API in the Google Fit App?

Tags: google-fitness-api

I have inserted several workouts (https://developers.google.com/fit/datatypes/activity)without error,
the result is 200.

But the workouts info is not shown in the Google Fit App.

Working with other data types like Heart Points (com.google.heart_minutes) or Duration (com.google.active_minutes) everything works correctly I can see in the session, but the specific workouts is not shown

thanks

rafa

Apparently the info about the workouts